# iOS AVFoundation: Get AVCaptureDevice.Format's video dimensions

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, avfoundation, avcapturesession

I'm trying to display the dimensions in which photos/video recordings can be taken to the user.

While photo dimensions are easily accessible through [`AVCaptureDevice.Format.highResolutionStillImageDimensions`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice/format/1624620-highresolutionstillimagedimensio), I have no idea how I can achieve the same for videos.

I've tried the [`AVCaptureDevice.Format.formatDescription.dimensions`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremedia/cmformatdescription/3242260-dimensions) property (or the [`.presentationDimensions(..)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremedia/cmformatdescription/3242280-presentationdimensions) func), but those just gave me the following compile errors:

[image]
[image: Console output]

Since those are available since iOS 13.0 (I believe that was Swift 5.1?), I should definitely have the API for those (especially since I can CMD + Click on them in my code), and my project should compile. Am I missing something here? Is there a better solution to get the resolution a capture device can record videos in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need below line.That's it.

```
   let dimensions = CMVideoFormatDescriptionGetDimensions(format.formatDescription)
```

Comment: Thanks! The "new" API (`.presentationDimensions`) got me thinking that there is no alternative. Good to know that the legacy ObjC methods still work.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct API to get the video resolution.
You can set the [AVCaptureSession.sessionPreset](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturesession/1389696-sessionpreset) to one of the [AVCaptureSession.Preset](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturesession/preset), then use [canSetSessionPreset(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturesession/1389824-cansetsessionpreset) to check if the preset is supported by the current device.

Answer (score 0):

I just did the following for testing and got all available video dimensions printed:

```
let descriptions = device.formats.map(\.formatDescription)
let sizes = descriptions.map(\.dimensions)
print(sizes)
```

I also checked if it compiled for iOS, Simulator, and macOS, and it does.

Are you still supporting iOS 12? Did you check your SDK setting?

Comment: I'm on min SDK version iOS 11, but it doesn't even compile with the `if #available(iOS 13.0)` check...

Comment: I just noticed that the same code does compile before another commit changed A LOT of project files (pbxproj, schema etc). before I start trying out changes from line to line and recompiling the (quite big) project, do you maybe have a guess where those compiler errors usually come from?

Comment: From the log I can only infer that it's trying to build for Simulator or macOS (`x86_64`), but not which SDK etc. Maybe you can post the corresponding compiler command?

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to respond. I've created a new S/O question for this since it seems a bit out of scope for this one, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66281687/swift-linker-error-undefined-symbol-for-surely-available-api-presentationdimens). I'd appreciate it if you could take a quick look